# Amazon pre signed url, allow only certain file types?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to use s3 to store content from users and govern access, in a social network type of service.

So far this is what I have thought of doing:

1. Client tells LAMP server he wants to upload a file
2. LAMP authenticates, and generates a presigned url for s3 where user can upload. It also creates an encrypted version of that key using private key. Then it adds this key, along with the user who started it in a mysql table(along with when it was started)
3. LAMP then sends the key and the digital signature from 2. to client.
4. Client then uploads the file to s3
5. After finishing, he tells LAMP that that file was completed. It sends in the key and the digital signature.
6. LAMP makes sure both the key and the signature match. If they do, LAMP knows that the client is honest about the key being given to him(and he has not randomly generated it)
7. LAMP then checks s3 to make sure that the file with that key exists, if it does,then delete the row which was added in 2.

My question is:

- Does the above data flow have some serious flaw, inefficiency ?
- How do I make sure the user is only allowed to upload only valid files(like png,jpg,pdf etc).I believe just checking the extension is not enough as it may be changed